# En MYSQL quiero una relación de 1:N (uno a muchos), pero no me sale :C

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

***Este es el código en la shell de mysql
El error que me salta es: ERROR: 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tallermecanico`.`vehiculo`, CONSTRAINT `FK_vehiculo_cliente` FOREIGN KEY (`PROPIETARIO`) REFERENCES `cliente` (`RFC`))***

CREATE DATABASE TALLERMECANICO;

use tallermecanico;

create table cliente(
RFC varchar(30) not null,
NOMBRES varchar(30) not null,
APELLIDOS varchar(30) not null,
DIRECCION varchar (50) not null,
EMAIL varchar (30),
TELEFONO varchar (15) not null,
primary key(RFC));

create table vehiculo(
PROPIETARIO varchar (30) not null,
PLACA varchar(10) not null,
MARCA varchar (10) not null,
SUBMARCA varchar (10),
YEAR int (5) not null,
primary key(PLACA),
FOREIGN KEY(PROPIETARIO) REFERENCES cliente(RFC)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);

insert into cliente values
("GU57835H2L", "Lola","Caballero Guerrero","Zumpango Estado de México","angelacg@gmail.com","5548521074"),
("J6LO92KDJ5", "Rosa","Rodriguez Nava","Valle de México","rosy@gmail.com","5565846454"),
("5O2JKH452L", "Luna","Martinez Rodriguez","Chapultepec","","5550623563"),
("AG8FH6FG52", "Alexis","Alvarez Morin","Calle Francisco I Madero","alexisalmo@gmail.com","5235879565"),
("FGH45F2GD4", "Mario","Soto Muñoz","Calle 5 de Mayo","soto0@gmail.com","5586597525"),
("H5G6HD6S3E", "Hugo Daniel","Fernandez Chávez","Calle Jose MA Morelos","hugoda@gmail.com","5548897584"),
("THGF847HD3", "Sofia Rosa","Navarro Bravo","Miguel Hidalgo, Mex","sofiro@gmail.com","5565865232"),
("DETE68DFS8", "Lucas Pablo","Vargas Montero","Cuahutemoc","","5550623563"),
("JK7KJH5KFH", "Beatriz","Andrade Gómez","Avenida Revolución","bea@gmail.com","5587956525"),
("95KGHJ54K2", "Lara","Guevara Alvarez", "Calle Carlos Diez Gutierrez","larague8@gmail.com","5586573521");

insert into vehiculo values
("GU57835H2L","NGF-92-58","Honda","Acura","2009"),
("J6LO92KDJ5","NGG-69-83","Volkswagen","Audi","2015"),
("5O2JKH452L","A-0003-A","Volkswagen","Bentley","2017"),
("AG8FH6FG52","E-0162-A","Hyundai","Genesis","2011"),
("FGH45F2GD4","B-13-464C","Nissan","Datsun","2013"),
("H5G6HD6S3E","A22-ALF","Hyundai","Kia","2011"),
("THGF847HD3","A-00-091","FCA","FIAT","2010"),
("DETE68DFS8","A-40-220","Nissan","Infiniti","2015"),
("JK7KJH5KFH","A-66-332","Toyota","Lexius","2017"),
("95KGHJ54K2","A-05-355","Renault","Venucia","2020"),
("KLJDFO4FG5","B-95-398","Renault","Venucia","2020"),
("KLJDFO4FG5","E-31-845","Honda","Acura","2007"),
("J6LO92KDJ5","E-0954-95","Volkswagen","Audi","2020"),
("DETE68DFS8","NGF-19-842","Nissan","Infiniti","2019");

*Se los agradecería mucho*

Comment: *pero no me sale* ... cual es el error? Con un query largo y con muy poca información será muy difícil identificar el problema. Mira [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: La tabla no se relaciona, me sale error: ERROR: 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tallermecanico`.`vehiculo`, CONSTRAINT `FK_vehiculo_cliente` FOREIGN KEY (`PROPIETARIO`) REFERENCES `cliente` (`RFC`))

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añádenos ese detalle :)

Comment: Listo, es nuevo esto muchas gracias.

Comment: Al parecer el error vendría a ser de las llaves foráneas. Intenta ejecutando esta consulta: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`

Comment: No tienes la menor idea de cuanto lo agradezco.

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor decirme que es lo que hace ese comando por favor?

De verdad muchas gracias Cris es para mañana me salvaste, es la única parte del código que fallaba.

Comment: Te hice una respuesta explicando la solución, también adjunté una documentación donde se explica aún más a detalle, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las llaves foráneas tienen restricciones de clave externa cuando son relacionadas con otras tablas. Estos errores ocurren cuando quieras modificar o eliminar columnas que ya son relacionadas con llaves foráneas de otras tablas.

Por defecto, estas verificaciones están definidas así:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS =  1;
```

Solamente tendrías que desactivarlo, ejecutándolo encima de tu consulta o realizando otra consulta luego de haber creado las tablas:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS =  0;
```

> *Enlace: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/set_foreign_key_checks*

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @Angela: Y activándolas nuevamente al final: `set foreign_key_checks = 1;`

Comment: Ahhh okey muchas gracias;